# Как сделать, чтобы функция  glRotatef()  не действовала на вторую линию ?

Tags: opengl

Как сделать, чтобы функция  `glRotatef()`  не действовала на вторую линию?  (opengl)

```
 glRotatef(g, 1, 0,0);

       glBegin(GL_LINES);  
       glVertex3f(x, y, z);
       glVertex3f(x, y, z);
       glVertex3f(x,y, z);
       glVertex3f(x, y, z);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте стек матриц OpenGL, чтобы запомнить текущую матрицу вида, и через некторое время к ней вернуться. Для этого в старых версиях OpenGL были две функции: [`glPushMatrix()`/`glPopMatrix()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml). Код получится такой:

```
   glPushMatrix();
     glRotatef(g, 1, 0, 0);
     glBegin(GL_LINES);
       glVertex3f(x, y, z);
       glVertex3f(x, y, z);
     glEnd();
   glPopMatrix();
   glBegin();
     glVertex3f(x, y, z);
     glVertex3f(x, y, z);
     // . . .
```

Но в современных версиях OpenGL эта функциональность считается устаревшей и не поддерживается (как и впрочем полностью **"immediate mode"** - т.е. рисование между операторными скобками `glBegin()` и `glEnd()`)

Comment: Теперь не работает glRotatef()

Comment: Моя ошибка - нельзя вызывать `glPushMatrix()` внутри `glBegin()/glEnd()`. Поправил ответ.